# Aws Lambda toolkit : Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0 error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, aws-lambda

So I've got this error when I'm launching my lambda locally.

I did put this in my csproj file

```
<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
```

It didn't resolve the issue, and when I'm running other lambdas on my computer, it runs fine

Also, creating another project in asp.net core 3.1 doesn't cause any issue.

This is my csproj file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
        <GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>
        <AWSProjectType>Lambda</AWSProjectType>
        <AssemblyName>Stuff.Anonymous</AssemblyName>
        <RootNamespace>Stuff.Anonymous</RootNamespace>
        <Configurations>Debug;Release;DEV;QA;LIVE</Configurations>
        <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
        <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Include="appsettings.json">
            <CopyToPublishDirectory>Always</CopyToPublishDirectory>
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
        <None Include="appsettings.*.json">
            <DependentUpon>appsettings.json</DependentUpon>
        </None>
        <Content Include="appsettings.$(Configuration).json">
            <DependentUpon>appsettings.json</DependentUpon>
            <CopyToPublishDirectory>Always</CopyToPublishDirectory>
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Include="logging.json">
            <CopyToPublishDirectory>Always</CopyToPublishDirectory>
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
        <None Include="logging.*.json">
            <DependentUpon>logging.json</DependentUpon>
        </None>
        <Content Include="logging.$(Configuration).json">
            <DependentUpon>logging.json</DependentUpon>
            <CopyToPublishDirectory>Always</CopyToPublishDirectory>
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <None Include="aws-lambda-tools-defaults.*.json">
            <DependentUpon>aws-lambda-tools-defaults.json</DependentUpon>
        </None>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Amazon.Extensions.Configuration.SystemsManager" Version="2.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.Core" Version="1.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json" Version="1.8.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.Core" Version="3.5.2.10" />
        <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.S3" Version="3.5.8.5" />
        <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="2.0.78" />
        <PackageReference Include="HtmlAgilityPack" Version="1.11.30" />
        <PackageReference Include="itext7" Version="7.1.14" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="5.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="5.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Hosting" Version="4.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Formatting.Compact" Version="1.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.Configuration" Version="3.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="3.1.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.Diagnostics.Debug" Version="4.3.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <Folder Include="Models\" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Thank you in advance, if you need more information, don't be shy :)

I wish you a wonderful day
[image]

Comment: What version of Net are you using?  Net 2.0 probably isn't loaded on machine.  Check in  control panel Software Installed to see what version of Net are loaded on machine.

Comment: How did you run/publish your lambda?

Comment: @jdweng I'm using .net core 3.1 for the lambda

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Yes, I can deploy and run the lambda on aws

Comment: @halonico What is your issue than? You can't it run locally?

Comment: The aws has Net 2.0 installed and your machine that is getting error does not have Net 2.0 installed.